# PHP Regular find url and email

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to find "http" and "https" and "email" inside text. I have tried:

```
    $regex = "((https|ftp)\:\/\/)"; // http and https
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)"; // email

    if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $comment))
    {
        $r = 'find';
    } else {
        $r = 'not find';
    }
```

with the following  text:

```
$comment = 'hello https:// and hello email mail@mail.com'
```

But it doesn't work. Probably because of wrong split.

I tried with filter like this:

```
    if (filter_var($comment, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return new \Exception('exist url');
    }
```

but when I have only email in comment filter, it works and finds this email, if I have 'hello mail@mail.com', it does not find the email.

For filter FILTER_VALIDATE_URL - it won't find the url if it is like this 'hello erl https:\hello'

How to write the right regex to find url or email in some text?

Comment: `^` in the beginning of your regex, means that the match should start at the beginning of the line. Thus, if you have some other content prior the email/url, you should not use it. Same is valid for `$` at the end of the pattern - only that it matches the end of the line, not the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $comment))
```

you have `^` then `$regex` and `$`. The `^` means to only match at the beginning of the line. The `$` means to only match at the end. Therefor, this would only match if that line contained *only* the match and nothing else.

Remove it to get matches anywhere in a line.

```
if(preg_match("/$regex/", $comment))
```

However, I would suggest to simply look for a library that offers the matching you are looking for. A library will have much more testing done to cover edge cases and other things that are easily missed.